# Did Ibn Taymiyyah believe in the Satanic verses?

Tags: ibn-taymiyyah

Is it true that Ibn Taymiyyah believed in the Satanic verses. I need verification on this quote which is alleged to be from him:

> The principle established by the agreement of the Community is that
> the Prophets (God’s Peace be upon them) are Protected in that which
> they convey from God (Glory be to Him) and in imparting his Messages.
> And it is by this firmly established Protection of the Prophets that
> the purpose of Prophethood and Messengership is obtained. A Prophet is
> someone who conveys communications from God and a Messenger is someone
> sent by God with a mission; and while every Messenger is a Prophet not
> every Prophet is a Messenger. Protection in regard to that which they
> impart from God is firmly established and the Muslims are agreed that
> no error may come to lodge therein. But: Can something issue forth
> which God then corrects, such that God removes that which Satan casts
> and establishes His Signs clearly? There are two opinions in regard to
> this and the Quran is in agreement with the one that has been
> transmitted from the early Muslims. Those later Muslims who forbid
> this position attack what has been transmitted about the Prophet
> uttering the additional words, “Indeed, they are as high-flying cranes
> And, indeed, their intercession is hoped for”, in Sirat al-Najm,
> saying that the transmission of the accounts is not established as
> reliable. Those of them who recognize that the transmission is
> reliable say: “Satan cast this into their hearing but the Prophet
> (God’s Peace and Preservation be upon him) did not utter it”; but the
> question remains unresolved in this interpretation too, so they also
> say in regard to God’s words, “‘illa idha tamanna alqa ‘l-shaytainu fi
> umniyyati-hi”, that this refers to inner thoughts. Those who affirm
> what has been transmitted from the early Muslims, say: This has been
> reliably transmitted and it is not possible to discredit it, and the
> Quran furnishes evidence for it by saying: “We have not sent before
> you a Prophet or a Messenger but that when he recited/desired, Satan
> cast something into his recitation, but God annuls that which Satan
> casts and then establishes His Signs [ayat] clearly – and God is All-
> Knowing, All-Wise – to make what Satan casts a trial for those in
> whose hearts is sickness and those whose hearts are hardened- for
> indeed the wrong-doers are in far dissension – and to teach those who
> have been endowed with knowledge that this is the Truth from your
> Lord, that they believe in it and humble their hearts to Him, for God
> guides those who believe to a straight path”. They say: The reports in
> explanation of this verse in the books of Tafsir and hadith are
> well-known and reliable and the Quran is in agreement with these
> reports.For God’s abrogation of what Satan casts and His establishing
> His Signs is precisely so as to remove what has fallen into His ayat
> and to distinguish Truth from Falsehood so that His diyat are not
> confused with anything else; while the making of that which Satan cast
> as a trial for those in whose hearts there is sickness and for those
> whose hearts are hardened” can only happen if what was cast was
> something external which the people heard and not something internal
> to the soul. The trial that results from this is the kind of trial
> that arises from the second category of abrogation and this category
> of abrogation is even stronger proof of the Veracity of the Messenger
> (God’s Peace and Pre- servation be upon him ) and of how far removed
> he is from following false desire than is the other category of
> abrogation. For, surely, if he enjoined that something be done and
> then enjoined something else that contradicted it, both commands being
> from God, and is considered as veracious in that; then when he said of
> his own volition that the second and abrogating command was from God
> and that the thing that was being removed and abrogated by God was not
> from God, this is an even greater proof of his purposing Veracity and
> of his speaking the Truth. This is similar to what ‘A’ishah (may God
> be pleased with her) said: “If the prophet had wanted to conceal any
> part of the Revelation, he would have concealed this verse: “And you
> concealed in yourself that which God was bringing to light and you
> feared the people when God is more to be feared”. Do you not think the
> person who seeks his own aggrandizement through falsehood would want
> to back up everything he says, even if it is wrong? **So the Prophet’s**
> **proclaiming that God had established his ayat and removed that which**
> **Satan cast is a yet greater proof of his striving for Veracity and his**
> **innocence from lying.** It is this that achieves the purpose of
> Messenger ship for indeed he is the Truthful, the Veracious, which is
> why calling him a liar is, without doubt, sheer Unbelief.
>
> [Ibn Taymiyyah and the Satanic Verses p.75](https://www.academia.edu/15003847/Ibn_Taymiyyah_and_the_Satanic_verses_Studia_Islamica_87_1998_67-124)

Comment: Yes, he believed in Satanic verses & it is explained by his student "Ibn Hadi" in "Kalam 'ala da'wat Dhi'l Nun", which is a lengthy commentary of Quran 21:87.. You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8CDvhM3arg) for more details..

Comment: Can you mark the time stamp where he mentioned IT because the length of the video is not ideal.

Comment: Watch 44:00 onwards..